# semaphores vs condition variables

Tags: operating-system, semaphore, condition-variable

There is a common problem : read/write problem in which only one writer is allowed to write  but multiple readers can read. It is usually implemented by semaphores. Can we use condition variables to solve this problem as well?

Comment: Don't see why not......

Comment: @MartinJames I tried solving it but couldn't. How can we let multiple users access reading function in parallel. Doesn't wait() and signal() let only one thread to perform execution. ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513045/conditional-variable-vs-semaphore

Comment: You can find some related information in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039899/when-should-we-use-mutex-and-when-should-we-use-semaphore